# update fields of table by an other PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

I have two tables

> **Table 1 :**

```
CREATE TABLE public.my_line
(
    id bigint NOT NULL,
    geom geometry,
    name character varying(254) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    CONSTRAINT my_line_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
```

> **Table 2 :**

```
CREATE TABLE public.ligne
(
    id integer NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('ligne_id_seq'::regclass),
    name text COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    geom geometry,
    CONSTRAINT ligne_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
```

I update the second by the first, like this :

```
update ligne set 
name = my_line.name 
from my_line 
where ligne.id = my_line.id
```

It works good, but what I want to do is being able to update just the rows that make difference between the two tables. If you have an idea in-light me. 
Cordially.

Comment: join both?.. and update from the join?..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check whether they are different in your `WHERE` clause. Try it like this:

```
UPDATE ligne
SET name = my_line.name
FROM my_line
WHERE ligne.id = my_line.id
AND ligne.name <> my_line.name
-- and whatever else you want to check for
```

Comment: Works as expected. Thank you!